# Raspberry PI reboot loop after apt upgrade failure

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, apt

i was upgrading from raspbian buster to bookworm on my Raspberry PI 4 B for a personal webserver. After installing a heck ton of updates (following [this tutorial from raspberrytips](https://raspberrytips.com/update-raspberry-pi-latest-version/)) and restarting, installing a new package led to another bulk of updates.

After presenting me with the usual important changelogs, it went about updating some ssl and crypto packages, then it tried to update libc6 or something (sadly i dont have the full outputs saved :( ). It also said: `/usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When retrying the command `sudo apt install libheif1 libheif-dev` i did previously, i got the Message `account validation failure, is your account locked?`. SSH refused my connection attempts from
My laptop. I then tried connecting the thing to a screen over hdmi and accessing it that way. It showee me this:
[What my tv screen displayed after 30 seconds from hooking up to power source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAxGi.jpg)

Next i will try the recovery mode.

Can someone please tell me what went wrong, what not to do next time and how i can get to where i was before the crash? Help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance to you guys.

Comment: "Can someone please tell me what went wrong" start with ignoring the official advice to perform a fresh install.